# airflow dag getting triggered more than once

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-api

I have a dag with one task, and I want it to get triggered only once a day. My problem is that it gets triggered multiple times when the time comes. So the daily task is run 4 times instead of once.
I set a number of configurations to fix that including:

```py
'retries': 1
```

```py
 catchup=False, max_active_runs=1
```

I also increased the time between retires thinking maybe airflow thinks the task has failed/not started since it might take some time for task to finish.

I also moved all the code that is supposed to run in that dag to utils folder based on this [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataengineering/comments/lyu1k5/comment/gpvte0e/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

But I don't know what am I missing here. Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance.

Here is the dag

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from utils.postgres import postgres_backup_to_s3

default_args = {
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),#getting backup and uploading to s3 might take some time
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1)
}

with DAG('postgres_backup', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 19 * * * *',
         catchup=False, max_active_runs=1) as dag:
    postgres_backup_to_s3_task = PythonOperator(task_id="postgres_backup_to_s3", python_callable=postgres_backup_to_s3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to run the job once per day at 7PM (1900) then your `schedule_interval` is incorrect. You want [`0 19 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_19_*_*_*).

In the Airflow documentation their examples for `schedule_intervals` consist of 5 space separated elements: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html#dag-runs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I changed the format and now the dag does not get triggered period.